# Parsing array of strings in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

If I have an `array` like this:

`myArray ="['John', 'Jack', 'Abe', 'Adelle' 'Jim', 'Andrew', 'Matthew']; ['Carpenter', 'Reaper', 'Lincoln', 'Aidan', 'Raynor', 'Doe']"`

where `myArray[0]` is `['John', 'Jack', 'Abe', 'Adelle' 'Jim', 'Andrew', 'Matthew']`

How can I get each name from `myArray[0]` and `myArray[1]` ?

Comment: Your question is confusing. The value looks like a string.

Comment: As far as i can tell, your `myArray[0]` is just 'John' (assuming you're actually converting your `string` to `array` object).

Comment: ya, myArray is a string here

Comment: My bad. I mean that myArray was an Array of 2 elements, where each element is a string with names. I got the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var splitted = myArray.replace(/\'/g, '"').split("; ");
myArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = JSON.parse(splitted[i]);
};
```

now `myArray` is 2d array with names.

Actually, if you'll run this code, you'll get an exception, but this is because you missed comma near `"Adelle" "Jim"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution :

```
var myArray ="['John', 'Jack', 'Abe', 'Adelle' 'Jim', 'Andrew', 'Matthew']; ['Carpenter', 'Reaper', 'Lincoln', 'Aidan', 'Raynor', 'Doe']"

arrays = myArray.split(";")
myArray= []
for(var a in arrays) {
    myArray.push(eval(a))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Tommi's idea of converting the string (it's not an array!) to JSON, here's another way to do it, this time without a loop:

```
var string ="['John', 'Jack', 'Abe', 'Adelle', 'Jim', 'Andrew', 'Matthew']; ['Carpenter', 'Reaper', 'Lincoln', 'Aidan', 'Raynor', 'Doe']";
var json = string
    .replace( /^/, '[' )
    .replace( /$/, ']' )
    .replace( /\]; *\[/g, '], [' )
    .replace( /'/g, '"' );
var array = JSON.parse( json );
```